# React native the release apk is not showing the modified or updated code

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, apk, gradlew

i am generating apk with gradlew assembleRelease /android/app the apk is successfully getting created, but the generated apk is not showing the latest or modified code. what could be the problem for this. any help would be thankfull.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: more details like? what shall i provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with `rm -rf node_modules && yarn` remove and install node package.
After that `cd android` then `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew bundleRelease` to install release bundle then run `react-native run-android --variant=release`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

be sure you are saving your code and clean your npm cache and react native cache , then try again , i hope it will help , use this link to clean your cache

https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d

Comment: after trying the above steps also i have faced the same problem